# What is .tt extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a project, where all .yml files have extension .yml.tt

For example:

```
/config/database.yml.tt
```

What do I do to get it working? My `rake db:migrate` doesn't know how to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is `tt` extension, but configuration files with sensitive and changeable information are often placed into `.gitignore` and instead of real files provide an example files (usually they are marked with `.example` extension - for example as [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/config)).

You should copy your file to `config/database.yml`, change it (if necessary) and run `rake db:migrate`

Detailed explanation: you have a root password on local DB - it means you need to provide it in `database.yml`. But other developers have own DB settings and they will need to change this file and setup own password after each code updating. When this file in `.gitignore` you can easy setup environment for own purposes (and you can look at example file) without breaking local environment for others.

Answer (score 0):

This is and old question, but since right now there are more tools you can use to build a templating system, I want to answer this other way...

.tt extension in that context commonly comes from Thor and ERB templates, it could a shorthand for Thor templates.

When you find this kind of files `.tt` probably it is supporting an automatic content generation process based on a template, in your case they are trying to define a template to build the configuration of the database.yml in an automatic way. That is how generators in Rails work, you could see [Rails Bytes](https://github.com/rails/thor) or [Ruby Bytes](https://github.com/palkan/rbytes) to get more info.